# How to print html tag content by removing the tag in veu js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have and object like this:

```
const obj= {
   tag: "<h3>This is content</h3>"
}
```

and in vue template, I want to use the tag key and print only the content .i.e. *This is content*. I am using bootstrapvue to print the content as:

```
<b-table-column label="label_name" field="name" sortable v-html="props.row.question">

</b-table-column>
```

but it prints the tag as well.

```
<h3>This is content</h3>
```

I want only *This is content*

Comment: I would suggest *not* mixing markup and content as a general rule.